# What are the names of all the keys Lucy has?

Tags: fairy-tail

Well I know there are a lot of keys. 
I always get mixed up on how there are silver, gold and other colors. 
It's all confusing! I don't get how Loke used his own magic to get in all the time. 
It's to confusing, I can't keep track. Help me please?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Gold Keys**

1. Gate of the water bearer key: Summoned the water Bearer, Aquarius.
2. Gate of the Golden Bull Key: Summons the Golden Bull,Taurus.
3. Gate of the Giant Crab Key: Summons the Giant Crab, Cancer.
4. Gate of the Maiden Key: Summons the Maiden, Virgo.
5. Gate of the Archer Key: Summons the Archer, Sagittarius.
6. Gate of the Lion Key: Summons the Lion, Loke.
7. Gate of the Twins Key:Summons the Twins, Gemini
8. Gate of the Ram Key:Summons the Ram, Aries.
9. Gate of the Scorpion Key: Summons the Scorpion, Scorpio.
10. Gate of the Goat Key: Summons the Goat, Capricorn.

**Silver Keys**

1. Gate of the Souther Cross Key: Summons the Southern Cross, Crux.
2. Gate of the Clock Key: Summons the Clock, Horolgium.
3. Gate of the Lyre Key: Summons the Lyre, Lyra.
4. Gate of the Canis Minor Key: Summons the Can is Minor, Nikora(Plue).
5. Gate of the Compass Key:Summons The Compass, Pyxis.

**Artifical Keys**

1. Celestial Spirit Banishment Key(former): Banishes the Maiden, Virgo.

Comment: Actually The gate of Lion's name isn't Loke, it's Leo but he uses Loke to act as human.